# Improve page speed by async and defer attribute

Tags: javascript, css, html, src

I need page speed improvement in my webpage.I read a lot about using `async` and `defer` `attribute` for improve initial page speed.All the `js` scripts are defined just above the `</body>` tag.Please suggest how effectively use these attributes in my page?

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style/mystyle.css"> 


</head>
<body>
<!--HTML content-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

google analytics script

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

To use defer:

```
<script src="path" defer="defer"></script>
```

To use async:

```
<script src="path" async="async"></script>
```

**When to use defer/async?**

If you need your scripts to be loaded asynchronously ie. while loading the html and css the script with asyc attribute will fore the browser to load them in background ie. they will be loaded while other things work.

And if you need your scripts to be loaded only after fully loaded the html and css then you may use defer attribute.

So, you need to be careful to use this technique because of these attributes some javascript code may not work as you wish it should have to be.

**How to use them effectively?**

I do not suggest you to use async because it may load any script in any order because of the filesize and/or scripts (as it loads asynchronously) so your functionality would be hampered.

So, just use the defer to fulfill the requirement as per the google page speed which will load the scripts as you wish it should have in that order.

Although, using defer, you may have impact on your website because you may have called some scripts should have run before the document is ready. In that case, you should not follow the instruction of the google page speed so let it be how it was.

Finally, it depends upon you and your scripts.

Comment: my question is how effectively add these attributes in this scenario?I already defined all js scripts at end of body tag.So using async or defer make any significant effect on page speed

Comment: Is it preferable to use async for Google  analytics code?

Comment: @akhilviswam yes. you can. but be careful and test yourself if all things are working...

Comment: In the above HTML which all scripts I can apply defer?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change anything or use `defer` for all.

`Bootstrap` requires `jQuery` to be loaded (although you're not really loading Bootstrap here, but some Angular-Bootstrap template). So you cannot use `async` to load any of these resources. Additionally you're loading a lot of `Angular` resources which depend upon the main `angular.min.js` resource, so you can't use `async` here either.

You could use `defer` for all, but the page won't render faster. The only difference is that the scripts will be executed once they're all loaded, rather than one by one (executed once they're downloaded), but that doesn't change anything regarding page load time.